# Install a specific version of Internet Explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer, version, downgrade

How can I install/downgrade to  a very specific version of IE11?

I need to have Version **11.0.9600.17501**.

Currently i have **11.0.9600.17801** installed.

So far i can't really think of a way how it could be done, since it isn't as easy as just downloading a Setup of an older Version of IE.

Comment: It is incredible how this hasn't been addressed or answered yet, not even from Microsoft Support Team members!

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there is no possible way to download an older version.

These are my sources:

[Source 1](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/all/how-can-i-download-a-specific-version-of-internet/a3aac5a4-469e-4c3d-9a72-0cc897d75968)

[Source 2](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/all/how-do-i-download-older-version-of-ie-11-ie-11020/ed4193a8-06ef-4dba-a253-33fdd7f3ee8b)

**HOWEVER,** as you can't download an older version, it's possible to find a computer that already has the version **11.0.9600.17501** installed.

Comment: I found the question on [this awesome Stack Overflow question finder](https://www.isimonbrown.co.uk/dicestack/)

Answer (score 0):

- Directly downgrading the internet explorer to your desired version is not supported by microsoft.
- I don't know if it'll really work but try using virtual machine.
- Install VMware and create a compatible windows OS for your desired version of internet explorer and see if you can install the version!